# Whats the best way to structure my js application, when my views / controllers need to be in the same file

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, scorm

I am Building a learning application where there are a bunch of different page types that a learner will go through and do activities. It will be a SCORM compliant learning object.

This is the structure I have so far...

```
application/
  models/
    scorm.js
    sequence.js
    session.js

  pagetypes/
    multichoice.js
    truefalse.js
    basic.js

  utilities/
    jquery.js
    api.js
```

My pagetypes do the viewing and the controlling, should I seperate these out? The reason I have combined them is so when I build a new page type, I can just drop it into that folder and it will get recognised straight away by the code.

What do you guys think? amidoinrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're separating out methods based on type of page interactions.

I don't see any reason not to do it your way. So long as everything the sco needs is in the manifest you can subdivide your scripts however you want. It might save just a bit of load time to separate out separate page types... But only if you are only loading what you need into the HTML page, & you are actually navigating pages within a sco session. If you're loading all script into a single HTML page, & then dynamically changing the content of page divs, then your scripts are all loaded 1 time & you may as well have 1 minified file for all page type scripts.

I would probably go with the latter, & tie interactions to classes or ids in the markup. 1 file, less work to minify, & I can use in other packages without having to make sure that I have every page type I need...

Comment: I am actually adding the pagetype class to the dom on the first time it gets used. Because the sequence is being built from a content authoring tool, theres no way to tell if I need all pagetypes or just two. Each page type then gets ajaxed onto the page.  
  
At the moment some generic pagetype methods live in the super class, it may be worth creating an interaction model.  
  
Cheers

Comment: Sounds like a awesome proj. :)

Answer (score 1):

With JavaScript it can be tricky to separate it out since it lives so closely to the view. As long as the data is separated from the actual view (which it looks like it is in your example) it will be a good design. I would argue that the pagetypes are more controllers and the HTML is the view. The most important part is to keep the model separated from the view. Unless you're trying to build reusable JavaScript/HTML components it's ok for pagetypes to blur the role of controller and view.